# How do I obtain the variadic arguments from an std::tuple to unpack for another std::tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, specialization, stdtuple

I am trying to convert a list of template arguments (enum class, not typenames) to corresponding typenames for the template arguments to an std::tuple. I'm guessing if I can get somehow name the variadic list as a `using type = ...`, I might be able to expand that in the next template recursion

So, I have the enum class:

```cpp
enum class object_t{
    STR,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
};
```

and the template supposed to provide the concrete class (some std::tuple):

```cpp
template <object_t _obj, object_t ...Args>
struct concrete {
        // here's the part I need to correct
    using type = std::tuple<typename concrete<_obj>::type, typename concrete<Args...>::type>;
};
```

the specializations to tail off the recursions:

```cpp
template <>
struct concrete<object_t::STR> {
    using type = std::string;
};

template <>
struct concrete<object_t::INT> {
    using type = int64_t;
};

template <>
struct concrete<object_t::FLOAT> {
    using type = double;
};
```

and the using declaration for the ::type shorthand

```cpp
template<object_t _obj, object_t ...Args>
using concrete_t = typename concrete<_obj, Args...>::type;
```

Eventually, I want something like

```cpp
concrete_t<object_t::INT, object_t::FLOAT, object_t::STR>
```

to be equivalent to

```cpp
std::tuple<int64_t, double, std::string>
```

Currently, that should produce something like:

```cpp
std::tuple<int64_t, std::tuple<double, std::string>>
```

instead.

I'm not the best on variadic templates, but i'm thinking if the using type (of the general template) was a parameter pack instead of a tuple, I might be able to unpack it for the next tuple (whose parameter list I will then have to obtain again and so on).
Something like:

```cpp
template <object_t _obj, object_t ...Args>
struct concrete {
    using type = std::tuple<typename concrete<_obj>::type, typename concrete<Args...>::type...>::elements_type;
};
```

where the elements_type is a variadic pack and the ::type... unpacks it

But even that doesn't seem right, since the root ::type will be a parameter pack and not an std::tuple like desired. Maybe another template is needed, I do not know.

Anything advice might go a long way, thanks!

Comment: Write a separate template that converts an enum to type, rather than having `concrete` do double duty. Then just write `template <object_t ...Args> struct concrete { using type = std::tuple<typename ObjectTraits<Args>::type...>; };`

Comment: Actually, it's not clear: do you want `concrete_t<object_t::STR>` to be `std::string` or `std::tuple<std::string>`? With your current approach, one-parameter instantiation is not symmetric with multi-parameter one - did you mean it this way?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for that. I want concrete_t<object_t::STR> to be std::tuple<std::string>, although I must admit I did not notice the ambiguity beforehand. It looks like your suggestion solves the problem, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone needs this, the solution, thanks to @IgorTandetnik, looks like this:

```cpp
enum class object_t{
    STR,
    INT,
    FLOAT,
};

template<object_t _obj>
struct concrete_traits;

template<>
struct concrete_traits<object_t::STR> {
    using type = std::string;
};

template<>
struct concrete_traits<object_t::INT> {
    using type = int64_t;
};

template<>
struct concrete_traits<object_t::FLOAT> {
    using type = double;
};

template <object_t ...Args> struct concrete {
    using type = std::tuple<typename concrete_traits<Args>::type...>;
};

template<object_t ...Args>
using concrete_t = typename concrete<Args...>::type;
```

This answer is based on @IgorTandetnik comment.

To eliminate the std::tuple in the trivial case of a single template argument, the specialization

```cpp
template<object_t _obj>
struct concrete<_obj> {
    using type = typename concrete_traits<_obj>::type;
};
```

makes, for example, `concrete_t<object_t::STR>` to be `std::string` instead of `std::tuple<std::string>`.

Comment: `concrete_traits` doesn't need to be a variadic template. Make it `template<object_t Arg> struct concrete_traits;`

Comment: True. Corrected that, thanks.